# what's the purpose of a local variable copy of internal array in dotnet collections source code

Tags: c#, .net, collections, variable-assignment, implementation

as dotnet collection Stack.cs source code

```
public T Peek()
{
    int size = _size - 1;
    T[] array = _array;

    if ((uint)size >= (uint)array.Length)
    {
          ThrowForEmptyStack();
    }

    return array[size];
}
```

there is a local reference copy of the backing array `T[] array = _array;`  [source here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/41d08f9d264d1a6f62cb2460634c6fd9f5251d38/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs#L195)

and a lot of similar codes in the Collections codebase.

What's the purpose of this? is it related to thread safety or any other consideration? Why just not use the class field `_array` instead?

I can't find any clues in google, so expecting some insights here.

Comment: someone could set a new value to `_array` and to prevent a race condition it gets the current reference

Comment: in case you need it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition

Comment: since _array is a reference type, mutation of the value will affect the local ref. and I can't see any re-assignment of the _array except in constructor.

Comment: @pinkli reassignment is in `Push` => `PushWithResize` => `Grow` via `Array.Resize(ref _array, newcapacity);` (and `EnsureCapacity` => `Grow`); also `TrimExcess`

Comment: @pinkli - assignment is "indirectly" through passing a reference of _array into a method eg. Array.Resize(ref _array, ...)

Comment: IMO it doesn't really serve a useful purpose. Any mention of a race condition ignores the reality that this type *is not designed for concurrent access*, and any such usage is undefined behaviour *anyway*.

Comment: @MarcGravell Possible better JIT optimization? I would imagine it could elide the bounds check, but only if it knew the array was the same object.

Comment: I think this is just a personal habit, since accessing local variables is slightly faster than accesing fields.

Comment: @shingo But in theory the JIT would know that and hoist the field access, given it's all the same function. Unless cross-threading risks, like I said.

Comment: @MarcGravell It’s still a cheap way to avoid at least *some* potential race conditions, even if the type as a whole isn’t designed for concurrent access. It’s maybe not extremely useful but it’s basic defensive programming: it can still prevent some bugs.

Comment: @Charlieface I think so because I used to have this habit, it is not relying on JIT optimization.  Furthermore, from Marc's answer it can be seen that this approach is commonly used in Stack.cs, but not in Queue.cs. The old Stack.cs also did not use this approach, perhaps the reason can be found from the history commits.

Comment: Oh I found [the commit of this optimization](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26086), unfortunately, it also mentioned that this copy [is not so necessary](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26086/files).

Comment: @KonradRudolph IMO reducing the visibility of bugs due to incorrect usage is a *bad thing*; we *want* that to explode in the most visible way possible - making a race harder to observe *makes it harder to realise there's a problem, to investigate, and to fix*

Comment: @MarcGravell I totally agree, I am an unapologetic proponent of fail-fast. But this particular change wouldn’t really reduce the visibility of any bug, since the resulting race condition is *already* hard to observe. In fact, the change simply makes a particular operation well-defined and well-behaved. It’s now *no longer a bug* to perform this particular concurrent operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to JIT optimization.

While the JIT [does have logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/clrcodegeneration/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr) to do bounds check elision, in the past it did not work if you refer to the field twice, rather than a local variable.

The function [`ThrowForEmptyStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8fbfb3204abba1eb7b42c617a656fa6aff8df84c/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs#L346) is known to be non-returning:

```cs
private void ThrowForEmptyStack()
{
    Debug.Assert(_size == 0);
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_EmptyStack);
}
```

So when the code does the check

```cs
if ((uint)size >= (uint)array.Length)
{
    ThrowForEmptyStack();
}
```

the JIT now knows that the array index cannot go out-of-bounds, because the bounds check has already been done. So it can elide the normal array bounds check in the generated machine code.

That [linked article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/clrcodegeneration/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr) mentions `static` fields, not instance fields, so it's not clear, but see [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/26086#discussion_r159071441) in the runtime repo. So in the past, if you used a field then it can't make that optimization. This seems to have been fixed, so the extra code was later removed.

Answer (score 3):

As per [the check-in comments for the change that introduced this temporary copy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/87938a1c2f775b3ce0878ba4343a7fed5ab50c32) this is nothing to do with thread safety.

Rather, it's to do with optimising the code by removing a bounds check:

> With value types the effect is not so big, because there is still one
> (manual) check for bounds. For reference types one bounds-check can be
> saved, so there is a win.

The comments and feedback for those changes are quite interesting; there's some discussion about whether the JIT will optimise away the bounds checking or not.

Comment: The (discussion around the) benchmarks feel slightly surreal to me… a check of the generated code would have been much more productive (and was done, just very late into the discussion, showing that the generated code is effectively the same, and the optimisation is pointless).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed - they might as well have reverted the change.

Comment: I think the optimization over fields was new at that point, could be they didn't realize.